# Copy two or more (.wav) files into one single file(Appending multiple .wav files in one file in android)

Tags: android, file, android-contentresolver, file-copying

I have got multiple files containing audio in .wav format/extension,
As **android** is not providing us with **AudioInputStream** how can i copy without it, below is the list of audioFiles:

```
List<File> audioFiles = new Arraylist<>();
for(File file : audioFiles) {
try...

catch...
}
```

I have been scratching my head since long time
Any help would be much Appreciated.
:-)

Comment: I wonder why you mess around with a vector and a sequence input stream. Do away with them. You iterate the arraylist and as soon as you have an input stream copy the contents to that output stream. Thats all.

Comment: all right this helped me:                        https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452687/10435571

Answer (score 0):

Actually OutputStream was missing a valid header so i created a helper class for writing a header for the file were all concatenated audio get written to.
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452687/10435571) helped me for Generating header for the (.wav) file

Comment: how did you merged multiple wav files into single one? 
I also trying to do same but the problem is new file only play the first file.

Comment: @Imranrana07 can u post ur code for merging wav files out here?